# Cannot insert values into database from HTML Forms

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble inserting values to the database from the HTML form. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/HhynqRnF

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: connect to database

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Connect to databse

Comment: Paste your code in your question. Url you provide may stop working in future.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to create [mysql connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) .and change your code into this code.

```
    <?php 
       $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_db"); //create connection
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {        

          $name = $_POST['fullname'];
          $username = $_POST['username'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];
          $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
          $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        }
      ?>

<form action="" method="post">


            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input name="fullname" type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Username<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input name="username" type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>


          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input name="email" type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input name="password" type="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Create Account</button>



          </form>
```

Comment: Sorry shubham, I actually had the connection line above but did not put the code here. Here is the entire code, still not working: http://pastebin.com/PEKuFYFW

Comment: have you try my code i have changed many things .please try this and print your query .

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
```